# What do the (Pali) suttas say about "sacrifice" in general (and why it's not necessary)?

Tags: reference-request, pali-canon, sutras

Requesting sutta references mentioning "sacrifice" along with pali words commonly (and uncommonly) translated as "sacrifice" along with thoughts and commentary please

Comment: Found this: There are some ascetics and brahmins who have this doctrine and view:
‘Purity comes from sacrifice.’
But it’s not easy to find a sacrifice that I haven’t previously offered in all this long time, when I was an anointed aristocratic king or a well-to-do brahmin. via https://suttacentral.net/mn12/en/sujato?layout=plain&reference=none&notes=sidenotes&highlight=false&script=latin

Comment: “Master Gotama, we brahmins sacrifice and enjoin others to offer sacrifices. Now both one who himself sacrifices and one who enjoins others to offer sacrifices engage in a meritorious practice that extends to many people, that is, one based on sacrifice. But one who leaves his family and goes forth from the household life into homelessness tames only himself, calms only himself, and leads to nibbāna only himself. In such a case, he engages in a meritorious practice that extends to only one person, that is, one based on going forth.” Then the answer via: https://suttacentral.net/an3.60/en/bodhi

Answer (score 2):

The Buddha discouraged animal sacrifice, human sacrifice, and other extra extravagant ritualistic sacrifices (soma juice drinking etc.), of which I quoted only part of the sutta of [AN 4.39](https://suttacentral.net/an4.39/en/sujato) below.

The Buddha however praised non-violent sacrifices, which I think refers to giving gifts (or contributing necessities) to family members.

Based on the dictionary entry given below for "*yañña*" (sacrifice), it seems like this term is used both for animal sacrifices and charity.

A similar teaching is given in [SN 3.9](https://suttacentral.net/sn3.9/en/sujato).

> “Does Master Gotama praise sacrifice (*yañña*)?”
>
> “Brahmin, I don’t praise all sacrifices. Nor do I criticize all
> sacrifices. Take the kind of sacrifice where cattle, goats and sheep,
> chickens and pigs, and various kinds of creatures are slaughtered. I
> criticize that kind of violent sacrifice. Why is that? Because neither
> perfected ones nor those who are on the path to perfection will attend
> such a violent sacrifice.
>
> But take the kind of sacrifice where cattle, goats and sheep, chickens
> and pigs, and various kinds of creatures are not slaughtered. I praise
> that kind of non-violent sacrifice; for example, a regular gift as an
> ongoing family sacrifice. Why is that? Because perfected ones and
> those who are on the path to perfection will attend such a non-violent
> sacrifice.
> [AN 4.39](https://suttacentral.net/an4.39/en/sujato)

From the PTS Pali-English dictionary [entry on "*yañña*"](https://dsal.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/app/pali_query.py?page=547):

> **Yañña** *Yañña* [Vedic *yajña*, fr. *yaj*: see [*yajati*](https://dsal.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/app/pali_query.py?page=547). The metric reading in the Veda is sometimes *yajana*, which we are inclined to look upon as
> not being the source of the P. *yajana*] 1. a brahmanic sacrifice. — 2.
> almsgiving, charity, a gift to the Sangha or a bhikkhu. The brahmanic
> ritual of Vedic times has been given a changed and deeper meaning.
> Buddhism has discarded the outward and cruel form and has widened its
> sphere by changing its participant, its object as well as the means
> and ways of "offering," so that the yañña now consists entirely in a
> worthy application of a worthy gift to a worthy applicant.

The Buddha also taught to not sacrifice one's own welfare for others in [Dhp 166](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/dhp/dhp.12.budd.html#dhp-166). The commentary for this verse can be found [here](http://www.tipitaka.net/tipitaka/dhp/verseload.php?verse=166). Please also read [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/19325/471).

> Let one not neglect one's own welfare for the sake of another, however
> great. Clearly understanding one's own welfare, let one be intent upon
> the good.
> [Dhp 166](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/dhp/dhp.12.budd.html#dhp-166)

Comment: The link to the Dhp-verses on The Self is really good, thanks.

Comment: The phrase "for example, a regular gift as an ongoing family sacrifice" is intriguing. What does it refer to?

Comment: Yes, what actually happened at a non-violent "ongoing family sacrifice" involving animals? Were they given to someone?

Comment: Also, are there other examples of non-violent sacrifices other than SN 3.9 and AN 4.39?