# what do you think of Miracles as mentioned in the Suttas and in the Oral traditions found in Hinduism and Buddhism?

Tags: ignorance, buddhist-miracles

I know one teacher who is an ok teacher, as far as he gets people to relax and make a good effort, but he really poo poo's any mention of Miracles in reference to the Buddha. I think that Full and complete awakening leads to mastery of the material world. Please give me your real belief in Miracles or not. Also. This same teacher explains some of the Miraculous activities of Arhants are just an activity of a different body, i.e. astral body, or a subtle body , and not really miracles.

Comment: This is phrased as a so-called "polling question" (i.e. "what do *you* think?"): a style that's discouraged by the [Moderation policies for Questions](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1572/254). This is identical to (a duplicate of) the "[Buddhism and miracles](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/26279/254)" question, isn't it? Except that the form of the other question allows answers which admit [it's controversial](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/114/254) (if it is).